# how to use and in the properties section of the html element in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, element

I had a situation like if 1st name exists in the obj , I need to do some more styling to that div so I am thinking like using and operator in react like this , if name exists add id to the div , but it is showing error

```
<div {obj["name"][0] && id="feature-border"} className="rectangle"> </div>
```

can anyone help me , how to use and in the properties section of the html element in react ??

Comment: `id={obj["name"][0] ? "feature-border" : null}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div {obj["name"][0] && id="feature-border"} className="rectangle"> </div>
```

Change this line of code to,

```
<div id={obj["name"][0] ? "feature-border" : ""} className="rectangle"> </div>
```

Or

```
<div id={obj["name"][0] ? "feature-border" : null} className="rectangle"> </div>
```

Comment: Note that this creates `<div id="" ...>` in the negative case, which is not the same as leaving out the `id` entirely (though it's close, and probably close enough for many purposes).

Comment: Yeah true, you can pass null if you want instead of ""